# Multiple failed dependencies in Azure Data Factory activity 'dependsOn'

Tags: azure-data-factory

When there are multiple activity dependencies ("dependsOn") conditions in an Azure Data Factory control activity do they all need to be true for the activity to run?

For example, if a clean-up activity should run if any other activity fails there can be several dependencies with a "dependencyCondition" of "failed".

```
"dependsOn": [
            {
                "activity": "FirstActivity",
                "dependencyConditions": [
                    "Failed"
                ]
            },
            {
                "activity": "SecondActivity",
                "dependencyConditions": [
                    "Failed"
                ]
            }
]
```

When there are multiple "Failed" dependencies will the activity run if any of them fails or only if they all fail?

I know I can just make each activity dependent on the next but that will may them run synchronously.  I'd like them to be able to run asynchronously and only run the clean-up activity if one or more of the activities it depends on fails.

Answer (score 1):

ADF dependencies use “and” operator, which means only all of them failed, the activity will be run.

In you scenario, I think you could add a cleanup activity for each activity.