# Error Handling on Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-data-factory

Team.

I have a situation to handle errors in ADF2 using Web Activity. Within a pipeline, any activity fails, it should trigger web activity. I attached the web activity after each activity's `failed` status. Therefore the web activity's `dependsOn` property looks like:

```
"dependsOn": {
  "activity1": [
    "Failed"
  ],
  "activity2": [
    "Failed"
  ]
}
```

However, the web activity only gets fired when all `activity1` and `activity2` are failed. What I wanted was to get that fired either `activity1` or `activity2` is failed. Instead, I used the `IfCondition` activity but it doesn't seem to be the right (correct or proper) way. What would be the best practice?

I tried to get all activities from filtering `pipeline().activities`, but it's not supported, either.

Comment: It would be so ironic if you could not OR these dependencies. This was a major  issue with DTS about 10 years ago. If this has cropped up again in ADFv2 that would be ludicrous.

Comment: This says they use AND, but does not suggest how they can use OR. Crazy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859359/multiple-failed-dependencies-in-azure-data-factory-activity-dependson/50860237

Answer (score 5):

You may try [ExecutePipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) with `waitOnCompletion`checked. Any inner pipeline failure within `ExecutePipeline` will make the outside `ExecutePipeline` fail.

Comment: Messy, but works. Looks like it's the only way for now.