# Capture HTTP 404 in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How do we capture HTTP 404 and not fail an ADF pipeline

The requirement is to check the HTTP response. If the HTTP response is 404, by default the Copy Activity fails with an error. But, we do not want to fail the pipeline. Instead, we want to check the response and stop further processing.

We have tried using Lookup activity, but the Lookup activity also fails, if we have a HTTP 404 response. We can write a Custom API and check the response in there, but, we do not want to do that.

Is there any native ADF way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

1.You could get idea of [Validation activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-validation-activity):

Activity will block execution until it has validated this dataset reference exists and that it meets the specified criteria, or timeout has been reached.

2.Also you could try to use [Execute Pipeline activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) to execute your specific pipeline and get the output of activity.([Error Handling on Azure Data Factory V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625549/error-handling-on-azure-data-factory-v2))

BTW,you could vote up this [feedback case](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/34301983-throw-error-activity) to push the progress about Throw Error Activity in ADF.

Comment: we did try the Validation activity. but, this did not work. It always gives time out irrespective of success or failure.

Execute Pipeline activity will just fail, which we don't want. We want to capture this info not fail.